# codenameone BluetoothLE startscan not compiling on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I am using the BluetoothLE library and I can compile for Android with no issues and it works but the same code does not compile for iOS.  I get the following

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,52 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Not supported on this platform
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not supported on this platform
at com.codename1.cordova.Cordova.execute(Cordova.java:26)
at com.codename1.bluetoothle.Bluetooth.startScan(Bluetooth.java:110)"
```

If I comment out my startscan line the application will compile.  The offending lines are below.

```
bt.startScan(new ActionListener() 
{  
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
bt_ScanDeviceFound(evt);
}
}, 
null, 
false, 
Bluetooth.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER, 
Bluetooth.MATCH_MODE_STICKY,
Bluetooth.MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT, 
Bluetooth.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES);
```

The [original code](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#startscan) from which the BluetoothLE was forked, from randdusing, shows different paramters for iOS than android. Maybe it has something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs if I try to execute the startscan before full UI initialization.  It does not cause an issue on Android builds.  So I moved the call to the startscan function after HomeForm.show();

Answer (score 0):

You can just catch the exception. This happens because bluetooth isn't supported by the screenshot capture process during iOS build. You can learn more about this process in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html).